# Asking for input in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
entry = input("Enter a word:")

if entry == whatever:
    print("print this")
```

I keep getting error whatever is not defined. Why? I want to define it through input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whatever` is a string which you are comparing your input with, so you need to put it in quotes. As in

```
if entry == 'whatever':
```

Now a small demo after the necessary edit will output

```
Enter a word:whatever
print this
```